# Boolean Understanding

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to wrap my head around a problem I am having with a practice problem using boolean expressions. I want to create a program that says if someone should ride a bike or not. I have two variables and want to write an AND statement and an OR statement. My two variables are road conditions and temperature.

Edit: With the help I received I have made a little progress. I have run into another issue in Line 22 from below;

```
// Program to decide if biking or driving to work is best

import javax.swing.*;

public class SNHU3_4Paper {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String temperature;
    String roadCondition;

    double temp;
    double weather = 50;
    double road;
    boolean roadIsdry = true;

    temperature = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter temperature outside: ");
    roadCondition = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is the road dry (true or false): ");

    temp = Double.parseDouble(temperature);
    road = Double.parseDouble(roadCondition);

    if (temp >= weather && road == roadIsdry)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bike to work");

    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Drive to work");

    }

}

}
```

Comment: When you are using a boolean, there's no 0 or 1. There's only true or false.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your current code and explained exactly what the you are trying to do.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second issue: `I have run into another issue in Line 22 from below`

You are comparing `roadIsdry`, which is a boolean, to `roadCondition`, which is a String, using `==`. You used `roadCondition` earlier to hold the user's input and then parse it.

In Java, comparing primitive types (int, boolean, double, etc) to objects using `==` pretty much doesn't work. Strings are objects. `roadIsdry == roadCondition` is literally asking Java "Is the **memory address** of `roadCondition` the same as the **boolean value** of `roadIsdry`?" and will always evaluate to false, because those two things are not the same, and don't even make sense to compare.

What you want to do is compare `roadIsdry` to a boolean, either `true` or `false`, or to another variable which is a boolean. You can also just specify `roadIsdry` by itself. `if (...)` expects to have a boolean as its final value to decide which branch of code to follow, so `if (roadIsdry)` is perfectly valid, as is `if (temp >= weather && roadIsdry)`.

Comment: I know. I just caught that and am updating my post with the new code now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I read your comments and see what you are saying. I fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To represent the road conditions as either dry or wet, a boolean value will suffice. For example, a boolean variable might be set up like so

```
bool road_is_dry = true;

if(road_is_dry){
  print("The road is dry");
} else {
  print("The road is wet");
}
```

In this case, the road is dry, so "The road is dry" would be printed. If the same variable were set to false, then the road is not dry (it is wet), so "The road is wet" would be printed.

This is an example of a conditional statement, where you are making a decision of which block of code should be executed. In can be very helpful when setting up conditional to use variable names that can be put together to make plain English sentences. Then basic sentences can be translated to code, and back again.

The plain English sentence "If the road is dry, ride your bike" can easily be translated to code if good variable and function names are picked, like so

```
if(road_is_dry){
  ride_bike();
}
```